# How to create a spinner group in Android?

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-gui

So, I have this activity in which a spinner is shown. There is also an add button on the right side of the button.

Once, the spinner item is chosen, the user can optionally tap on the add button. Once the user taps on it, a new spinner has to be created at the place of the button which was clicked(next to the first spinner). After this, a new add button should be created next to the now created second spinner. So this can go on until the user wants to.

Note: All the spinners have the same string array content.

Please help!

EDIT 1: Here's my code
Java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class AccountSetupGradesActivity extends Activity {
    Spinner grades_spinner;
    Button addButton1;
    Button addButton2;
    Button addButton3;
    Button addButton4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_account_setup_grades);

        grades_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.gradesSpinner);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.grades_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        grades_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        addButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addSpinnerButton1);
        addButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addSpinnerButton2);
        addButton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addSpinnerButton3);
        addButton4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addSpinnerButton4);

        addButton2.setEnabled(false);
        addButton3.setEnabled(false);
        addButton4.setEnabled(false);
    }


}
```

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="103dp"
        android:text="@string/grades_text_view" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/gradesSpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/addSpinnerButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/gradesSpinner"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/addSpinnerButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/addSpinnerButton1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/addSpinnerButton1"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/addSpinnerButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageButton01"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/addSpinnerButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageButton02"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageButton02"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Well, I had no idea what to do. But I tried something. I created ImageButtons. But, only the first button would be enabled when the Activity starts. But when the first add button is clicked, the spinner would be created and the next add button would be enabled. This seemed kinda messed up, so I deleted it. Thanks.

Comment: Show your code. Here's not a code shop. We are here to help you with your existing code, not to write new code for you.

Comment: I didn't create any of the methods because I had no idea of what to do.

Comment: First, you need some Click event handlers (it can be done in several ways - I recommen you to study which one is the right in this particular case). Then you want to create controls at run time (and also on this argument, there's a plenty of examples). After all you have to search 3 things: jow to get an array of strings from resources and assign it to a Spinner, how to create and manage Views at run time, and how to assign click handlers. Then put all together.

Comment: Glad to have pointed you in the right direction. After all, these are all things you have to learn (you will often use them) sooner or later. Better sooner.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, I am 13.

Comment: Great! It's good to have a passion when you're young and possibly make a profession out of it!